# std::regex cannot find a text when \n or \r is at the end of the line

Tags: c++, regex, std

See the code below:

```
const std::string line = "myemail@gmail.com";
const std::string egrep = ".*gmail.*";
std::regex        txt_regex(egrep.c_str());

if (!std::regex_match(line, txt_regex)) {
    std::cout << "Not matched?!" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Matched" << std::endl;
}
```

It will print out **Matched**.
However, if I end that line with CR or LF (\r or \n respectively) it will print **Not matched?!**

Is that a bug or expected reaction on CR with default regex flags?

Comment: `.` does not match line break chars and `regex_match` requires the full string match, so `string\n` won't match. Use `regex_search` to find a partial match or replace `.` with `[\s\S]` / `[^]`.

Comment: This seems to have been hastily closed.  However, I don't feel it was entirely justified.  The proper answer to what you are asking centers on the fact that the `.` wildcard matches any character _except_ newline.  Newline is considered either CR or LF, so if you want to allow those in a full match, then use `".*gmail.*[\r\n]*"`.  It should be noted though, that these are strictly not valid characters for an email address, so depending on what you're using this for, you may first want to _sanitize your inputs_.  Alternatively, a `regex_search` with the pattern `"gmail"` would achieve the same.

Comment: The dupes look appropriate to me. Don't know what's too hasty when pointing someone to the answer.

Comment: I disagree it should be closed as the examples of the answers are not matching the case. These examples are much wider, so would require different type of a question when looking for an answer to this specific case.